# Installation is not working for Ubuntu in hp probook g3 440

Tags: grub2, usb-installation

I have been trying installing ubuntu in my laptop with a bootable live usb (Ubuntu 20.04 and also other versions 64 bits). first the installation was stacking or frozeen, I solve that using in the grub terminal pressing E in ubuntu "acpi=off". Then proceeds to the installation but at the end is a message that the installation is crashed. When I restart the laptot goes directly to the Grub's terminal. Also I have tryed with boot-repair but the basic task is not working so I should to do: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7pxbNj3dB8/

Someone knows what is wrong because I'm pretty lost I've read a lot of forums and watched a tons of videos. Thank you in advance.

Boot-repair output:

```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
 11
 12
 13
 14
 15
 16
 17
 18
 19
 20
 21
 22
 23
 24
 25
 26
 27
 28
 29
 30
 31
 32
 33
 34
 35
 36
 37
 38
 39
 40
 41
 42
 43
 44
 45
 46
 47
 48
 49
 50
 51
 52
 53
 54
 55
 56
 57
 58
 59
 60
 61
 62
 63
 64
 65
 66
 67
 68
 69
 70
 71
 72
 73
 74
 75
 76
 77
 78
 79
 80
 81
 82
 83
 84
 85
 86
 87
 88
 89
 90
 91
 92
 93
 94
 95
 96
 97
 98
 99
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
112
113
114
115
116
117
118
119
120
121
122
123
124
125
126
127
128
129
130
131
132
133
134
135
136
137
138
139
140
141
142
143
144
145
146
147
148
149
150
151
152
153
154
155
156
157
158
159
160
161
162
163
164
165
166
167
168
169
170
171
172
173
174
175
176
177
178
179
180
181
182
183
184
185
186
187
188
189
190
191
192
193
194
195
196
197
198
199
200
201
202
203
204
205
206
207
208
209
210
211
212
213
214
215
216
217
218
219
220
221
222
223
224
225
226
227
228
229
230
231
232
233
234
235
236
237
238
239
240
241
242
243
244
245
246
247
248
249
250
251
252
253
254
255
256
257
258
259
260
261
262
263
264
265
266

    

boot-repair-4ppa125                                              [20200827_2231]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on sda2

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, focal, x86_64)


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot enabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 000E
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 000E,0010,0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,0007,0008,0009,000F,000A
Boot0000  Startup Menu  FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)....ISPH
Boot0001  System Information    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0002  Bios Setup    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0003  3rd Party Option ROM Management   FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0004  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0005  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0006  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0007  System Diagnostics    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0008  Boot Menu FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0009  HP Recovery   FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot000A  Administración de ROM opcional de terceros    FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot000C* IPV6 Network - Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(c8d3ffecbc01,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot000D* IPV4 Network - Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(c8d3ffecbc01,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot000E* Flash USB Disk 3727011FEE45759313359  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(3,0)N.....YM....R,Y.....ISPH
Boot000F  Network Boot  FvVol(a881d567-6cb0-4eee-8435-2e72d33e45b5)/FvFile(9d8243e8-8381-453d-aceb-c350ee7757ca)......ISPH
Boot0010* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,a7860bf7-aa39-4bc5-85a5-6f98ca1ff949,0x800,0x1dc800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)....ISPH

bed45d1c9554cea09924d3814cb7c446   sda1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   sda1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
1476c8ed1ce8271aab2fbe89d534cfa4   sda1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   sda1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   sda1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   sda1/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
sda3    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda3    : maybesepboot, no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 2B8C6C4F-14F4-4C33-9423-70AE14E8C4B0
          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sda1       2048    1953791    1951744   953M EFI System
sda2  115234816 1953523711 1838288896 876.6G Linux filesystem
sda3   70313984  109375487   39061504  18.6G Linux filesystem
sda4  109375488  115234815    5859328   2.8G Linux swap
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sdb: 3.77 GiB, 4026531840 bytes, 7864320 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x56f48570
      Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *          0 5439487 5439488  2.6G  0 Empty
sdb2       5017392 5025327    7936  3.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sdb3       5439488 7864319 2424832  1.2G 83 Linux

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA WDC WD10SPCX-60K:;
1:1049kB:1000MB:999MB:fat32::boot, esp;
3:36.0GB:56.0GB:20.0GB:ext4::;
4:56.0GB:59.0GB:3000MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
2:59.0GB:1000GB:941GB:ext4::;
sdb:4027MB:scsi:512:512:unknown:Flash USB Disk:;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                
├─sda1 vfat     22CE-58D1                            a7860bf7-aa39-4bc5-85a5-6f98ca1ff949                          
├─sda2 ext4     aa78735e-f732-4d0e-9508-62b0b8a11a90 7ca22485-6f80-4c6c-8cc1-b56e718a6036                          
├─sda3 ext4     5d32350a-f0bb-4275-b2a1-610a93d05512 d50787c8-b4b5-40b7-9393-ae2c5c7e6db3                          
└─sda4 swap     8f810d97-0b2a-42a7-bf14-bd7c50b98eb9 24d98dff-e032-4fc8-b1ce-4e7843d000b2                          
sdb    iso9660  2020-07-31-16-51-12-00                                                    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS amd64 
├─sdb1 iso9660  2020-07-31-16-51-12-00               56f48570-01                          Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS amd64 
├─sdb2 vfat     C26E-047E                            56f48570-02                                                   
└─sdb3 ext4     2b6c3e7e-4351-48ee-91de-b6b46c46eb0b 56f48570-03                          writable                 

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

                                                          Avail Use% Mounted on
disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2020-08-28.2/crash]      0  98% /var/crash
disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2020-08-28.2/log]        0  98% /var/log
sda1                                                     943.4M   1% /target/boot/efi
sda2                                                     810.6G   1% /mnt
sda2                                                     810.6G   1% /target
sda3                                                      17.2G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
sdb1                                                          0 100% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2020-08-28.2/crash] rw,relatime
disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2020-08-28.2/log]   rw,relatime
sda1                                                     rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
sda2                                                     rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
sda2                                                     rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
sda3                                                     rw,relatime
sdb1                                                     ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048

========================== sda2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=aa78735e-f732-4d0e-9508-62b0b8a11a90 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=22CE-58D1  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 269.084133148 = 288.926887936  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
  59.260738373 = 63.630733312   boot/vmlinuz                                   2
  59.260738373 = 63.630733312   boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic                  2
 587.978725433 = 631.337349120  boot/initrd.img                                3
 587.978725433 = 631.337349120  boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic               3
 587.978725433 = 631.337349120  boot/initrd.img.old                            3

===================== sda2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17123 Jul 30 20:34 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42128 Jul 30 20:34 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Jul 30 20:34 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Jul 30 20:34 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Jul 30 20:34 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Jul 30 20:34 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Jul 30 20:34 41_custom


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on sdb

00000000  45 52 08 00 00 00 90 90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ER..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  33 ed fa 8e d5 bc 00 7c  fb fc 66 31 db 66 31 c9  |3......|..f1.f1.|
00000030  66 53 66 51 06 57 8e dd  8e c5 52 be 00 7c bf 00  |fSfQ.W....R..|..|
00000040  06 b9 00 01 f3 a5 ea 4b  06 00 00 52 b4 41 bb aa  |.......K...R.A..|
00000050  55 31 c9 30 f6 f9 cd 13  72 16 81 fb 55 aa 75 10  |U1.0....r...U.u.|
00000060  83 e1 01 74 0b 66 c7 06  f3 06 b4 42 eb 15 eb 02  |...t.f.....B....|
00000070  31 c9 5a 51 b4 08 cd 13  5b 0f b6 c6 40 50 83 e1  |1.ZQ....[...@P..|
00000080  3f 51 f7 e1 53 52 50 bb  00 7c b9 04 00 66 a1 b0  |?Q..SRP..|...f..|
00000090  07 e8 44 00 0f 82 80 00  66 40 80 c7 02 e2 f2 66  |..D.....f@.....f|
000000a0  81 3e 40 7c fb c0 78 70  75 09 fa bc ec 7b ea 44  |.>@|..xpu....{.D|
000000b0  7c 00 00 e8 83 00 69 73  6f 6c 69 6e 75 78 2e 62  ||.....isolinux.b|
000000c0  69 6e 20 6d 69 73 73 69  6e 67 20 6f 72 20 63 6f  |in missing or co|
000000d0  72 72 75 70 74 2e 0d 0a  66 60 66 31 d2 66 03 06  |rrupt...f`f1.f..|
000000e0  f8 7b 66 13 16 fc 7b 66  52 66 50 06 53 6a 01 6a  |.{f...{fRfP.Sj.j|
000000f0  10 89 e6 66 f7 36 e8 7b  c0 e4 06 88 e1 88 c5 92  |...f.6.{........|
00000100  f6 36 ee 7b 88 c6 08 e1  41 b8 01 02 8a 16 f2 7b  |.6.{....A......{|
00000110  cd 13 8d 64 10 66 61 c3  e8 1e 00 4f 70 65 72 61  |...d.fa....Opera|
00000120  74 69 6e 67 20 73 79 73  74 65 6d 20 6c 6f 61 64  |ting system load|
00000130  20 65 72 72 6f 72 2e 0d  0a 5e ac b4 0e 8a 3e 62  | error...^....>b|
00000140  04 b3 07 cd 10 3c 0a 75  f1 cd 18 f4 eb fd 00 00  |.....<.u........|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001b0  f4 8d 05 00 00 00 00 00  70 85 f4 56 00 00 80 00  |........p..V....|
000001c0  01 00 00 a5 e0 ff 00 00  00 00 00 00 53 00 00 fe  |............S...|
000001d0  ff ff ef fe ff ff 30 8f  4c 00 00 1f 00 00 00 97  |......0.L.......|
000001e0  46 52 83 87 5e e9 00 00  53 00 00 00 25 00 00 00  |FR..^...S...%...|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

File descriptor 63 (pipe:[218692]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 51017: /bin/bash

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
sda2,
using the following options:        sda1/boot/efi,
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s  use-standard-efi-file    

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

/target detected. Please close the Ubuntu installer, then retry. 

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________


Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS entry (sda1/efi/****/shim****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
```